# How do I get list of field objects in a table in web2py?

Tags: web2py

How do I get a list of all the field objects (e.g. `gluon.dal.Field`) in a table?
The following

`db.customer.fields`

just returns a list of strings which are the field names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
field_objects = [f for f in db.customer]
```

Comment: Oh I see it implements `__iter__` with this functionality, good to know.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I see that fields are defined as attributes of the table class (`gluon.dal.Table`).  The table class has a [`__getitem__`](http://www.web2py.com/examples/static/epydoc/gluon.dal-pysrc.html#Table.__getitem__) method defined which allows indexing by attribute name (as [python allows](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names)).

Therefore I can get a list of field objects by using a list comprehension:

```
[db.customer[fieldname] for fieldname in db.customer.fields]
```